# "which" after a dash

Tags: grammar

From [this New Yorker article](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/comment/2013/09/sanity-on-pot-and-stop-and-frisk.html):

> But Holder’s decision suggests (though it does not guarantee) that marijuana arrests will be heading downward. To the extent that they do, that will be a step forward for racial equality. Ending discriminatory enforcement—**which** is what happened in New York and around the country—is a positive step for everyone.

What does this "which" refer to?

Comment: In this sentence, *which* stands for *ending discriminatory enforcement*.

Comment: but obviouisly from the context, it hasn't happened yet...only in New York and Colorado and Washington...so I thought it was just discriminatory enforcement.

Comment: I'd say it's just "discriminatory enforcement" that the "which" is referring to.

Comment: oic. Well, I personally have no idea whether in the real world what happened in NY was *discriminatory enforcement* or the ***ending** of discriminatory enforcement*. The actual text you've quoted is ambiguous in that respect - I just chose the interpretation that seemed most credible to me (I'm assuming NY isn't famous for having *introduced* discriminatory enforcement). I've removed my downvote because it's not quite as trivial as I thought, but in terms of *English **language*** I rather think it's just a matter of opinion. The words themselves *are* ambiguous.

Comment: the full idea (noun) is "ending discriminatory enforcement", so the pronoun `which` refers to this idea

Comment: Andy, having seen the last 10 or so of your questions, I feel I should once more urge you to check out [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). Your questions would be very welcome there but are really quite basic for ELU. In general we avoid questions that every native speaker could answer.

Comment: Andy, I also note that you've asked 15 questions in the last 2+ weeks, & had answers on most, with multiple answers on several - yet you haven't *accepted* a single answer to any of them. *Does this mean that none of the many answers you have received actually answers any of your Qs?* If they *do* answer your Qs, then *please accept the best one* (after waiting a little to see if you get better ones). It is polite to accept an answer on each Q. where possible, and encourages people to continue helping you. Please see [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited to [ell.se]

Answer (score 4):

From a purely syntactic perspective, the wording is ambiguous. "*Which*" here could apply to either "discriminatory enforcement" or "ending discriminatory enforcement".

Given that the article gives no indication that discriminatory enforcement has ended "around the county", it likely was meant to apply only to "discriminatory enforcement". Indeed, if the author believed that discriminatory enforcement *had* ended around the country, it seems unlikely that the article would have been written at all.

Comment: The full text of the article shows that you're undoubtedly correct:  http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/comment/2013/09/sanity-on-pot-and-stop-and-frisk.html