# "Same as I do" or "same as I have"

Tags: grammar

*She has the same book as I have.*

Isn't it supposed to be *She has the same book as I do*?

But I often hear the former.

Why?

Comment: She has > I have - same verb!

Comment: Asking 'Why?' is 'primarily opinion based and therefore off topic.

Comment: As @terdon said in a comment on a [recent question of yours](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/125152/43980), your questions are much better suited to [ell,se]. And as I said in another comment on that question, you should be ***accepting*** the best answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try my best to answer the "why" part of the question. I prefer giving visual examples rather than writing paragraphs of grammar, hopefully, this ought to explain : "*I can't spot a reason why the second is ungrammatical, but it grates on my ear*."

In British English it is common to inverse the position of the auxiliary verb, have, with the subject to form a question.

> "**Has** she (got) the same book as mine? or
> "**Has** she (got) the same book
> as me?"(informal)

You can therefore construct positive sentences in this manner:

> She has got the same book **as I have** (BrEng)
>
> She has the same book **as I** (very formal) or
>
> She's got the same book **as me** (informal)

In American English it is more common to use the auxiliary verb, do, to make the question form.

> "***Does*** she have the same book as mine? or
> "***Does*** she have the same book as me?"

This is, I believe, where your logic has led you to surmise the positive sentence should be said or written as;

> She has the same book as I **do**.

Whereas it is more correct to say,

> She has the same book as I (have).

Answer (score 2):

I can't spot a reason why the second is ungrammatical, but it grates on my ear.

I would only ever say or write the former "*She has the same book as I have.*", probably to retain the *possessive* inference of *to have*.

Comment: Just curious: If you were asked, "Do you have that book?"  Would you answer, "I have."  or "I do."?

Comment: Nineteen times out of twenty I would answer "I do.", as you of course already expected; I am actually unsure about the twentieth time. I claim no great logic behind my thoughts above, hence the hesitation on my rationale.

Comment: I'm fairly certain (though I can't quickly find an article endorsing this view) that there is a strong US / UK divide on which verb to choose in these types of constructions. The 'UK version' (She has the same book as I have.) is licensed by 'She and I have the same book.' and is often ellipted to 'She has the same book as I.' The 'US version' (though there's no law saying it's unpatriotic to choose the alternative!) can be considered as an ellipted form of 'She does have the same book as I do.' (Though this seems a less logical {but equally grammatical} expression to start off with.)

Comment: In response to Do you have that book? You'd say: Yes I have it.