# "as I did", "as I have", or "as me"

Tags: grammar

Which of the following, if any, is correct?

- You answered the same questions as me.
- You answered the same questions as I did.
- You answered the same questions as I have.

How can you tell?
I tried Googling it, but I only get Breaking Bad references.

I also saw [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125228/same-as-i-do-or-same-as-i-have), but I don't know how it would apply in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two are both fine. The third one doesn't work because there is no *have* in the main sentence, so the tenses don't match, which sounds odd. But

> You have answered the same questions as I have.

would be fine.

Comment: I don't think the first one is correct.  It's common to say things that way, but I don't believe it's grammatical.

Comment: It is perfectly grammatical, and the people who claim otherwise prefer a set of arbitrary made-up rules to understanding how English actually works.

Comment: Then I guess I have "no understanding of the grammar of English."

Comment: Sorry, @amt528 - I edited my comment to something a bit less dismissive, which is why your comment no longer seems to follow.

Comment: @amt528 I think it depends on the context.